# Debugging binary trees

Tags: c#, debugging, binary-tree, debuggervisualizer

I've written a quite primitive binary tree and it works just fine. The problem is, debugging it is a pain, actually seeing what each node contains and all their children and grandchildren is very tedious. Are there any visualizers so I can just get a tree representation of the data when I'm debugging it?

Answer (score 2):

You can build "poor man's visualizer" by overriding `ToString` and producing a tree representation that humans can read, like this:

```
string ToString() {
    var leftSub = left != null ? left.ToString() : "-";
    var rightSub = right != null ? right.ToString() : "-";
    return string.Format("[{0}:{1},{2}]", data, leftSub, rightSub);
}
```

For example, for a binary tree that looks like this

```
      6
     / \
    /   9
   3
  /  \
 1    4
```

this code should produce this output:

```
[6:[3:[1:-,-],[4:-,-]],[9:-,-]]
```

Comment: If you cannot override ToString, consider using the DebugDisplayAttribute: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228992(v=vs.110).aspx which you could assign an arbitrary method to display the visual representation.